# В чем отличие General и Request Headers в Network?

Tags: http, request

Когда я отправляю запрос на сервер то в вкладке Google Chrome Netvork я вижу такую картину:

```
General
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/get_all_proposes/add_propose?
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Referer:http://localhost:8080/get_all_proposes
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36
```

В чем отличие? Если я правильно понимаю то все что под заголовком `Request Headers` я получу на сервере (поправьте если я не прав). А что такое General?

Comment: Основные заголовки (англ. General Headers) являются основными для запросов клиента и ответов сервера. Большая часть из них являются обязательными.  Referer - Полный или относительный URI ресурса, с которого клиент сделал текущий запрос. Если указан относительный, то полный определяется по запрашиваемому URI. Клиенты не должны включать в значение Referer указатель фрагмента (часть URI после символа решетки «#»). Также нельзя включать ссылки на ресурсы, не имеющие собственного URI (например, ввод адреса с клавиатуры).